# In JMS 2.0 factory.createContext() is throwing AbstractMethodError

Tags: jms2

I am using ActiveMq as provider and JMS 2.0 API.
The second line is throwing **AbstractMethodError**, how to fix it?

```
1. ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
2. JMSContext context = factory.createContext();
3. context.createProducer().send(destination, msg);
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext()Ljavax/jms/JMSContext;
    at jms.advance.Sender.sendMessage(Sender.java:41)
    at jms.advance.Sender.main(Sender.java:26)`

The ***destination*** object I created using following steps.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);   
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue("SAMPLE_test_QUEUE");
```

Below is complete snippet of code.

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Sender {
    public String senderId;
    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Destination destination = null;

public static void main(String... arg) throws JMSException, InterruptedException{
    Sender sender = new Sender("facebook");
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0; i <= 100; i++, count++){
        String msg = sender.senderId +": "+ "sending msg #" + count;
        sender.sendMessage(sender.factory, sender.destination, msg);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
public Sender(String senderid) throws JMSRuntimeException, JMSException {
    this.senderId = senderid;
    factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    destination = session.createQueue("SAMPLE_test_QUEUE");

}

public void sendMessage(ConnectionFactory factory, Destination destination, String msg) throws JMSException{
    try(JMSContext context = factory.createContext()){
        context.createProducer().send(destination, msg);
    }catch(JMSRuntimeException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory is correct, activemq does not yet support JMS2. (the related issue in their JIRA is still open : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5383 )

So the `createContext()` method will not yield the expected results. However you can still use the method `createConnection()` to do the work since JMS2 has JMS 1.1 backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Vaaith, I should have check the Activemq support for jms2.0.

Comment: ActiveMQ: no support for JMS 2.0
IBM MQ Version 8.0: supports JMS 2.0

Comment: Here you can find the code for,- `createConnection()` usage, under the link,- https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms20.html